# How do companies benefit from increase of shares value in the stock market?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, financial-literacy, stock-exchanges, shares

I am completely ignorant on the subject and am trying to understand the fundamentals of finance in order to better understand some topics for example how the exchange market works.

**This is what I understood:** if a company is listed on the stock exchange, it issues shares, for example 100 shares at a value of 1 euro each. If I buy a share I "own" 1% of the company and the dividends will be proportional to the number of shares I own (I assume).

**Problem # 1:** If the value of the stock I own increases due to demand, what benefit does the company get? After all, it made 1 euro from my initial purchase and it is not affected by the fact that I can sell my share to someone else at a higher price.

**Problem n2:** a possible answer to my question is that the company can place new shares on the market that will be purchased at a higher price than the initial 1 euro given the higher demand. In this case, however, I would "own" less than 1% of the company as more people have bought it. Consequently my dividends could be lower, forcing me to sell the shares to maximize the profit. And this does not really make sense to me to be honest, as it would generate negative feedback.

Would anyone be kind enough to explain to me what am I wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: For the second question, it depends on what the company _does_ with the proceeds - if the company uses them to grow, then your dividends could still rise, since you'd own a smaller percentage of a bigger "pie".

Comment: An answer to the second question [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/51705)

Comment: See **[Why would a company care about the price of its own shares in the stock market?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7800/why-would-a-company-care-about-the-price-of-its-own-shares-in-the-stock-market)**

Comment: Thank you everybody for the comments!! I really appreciate it! :)